# What is the best method to achieve dynamic URL Rewriting in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, routes, url-rewriting

I'm currently using [Intelligencia.UrlRewriter](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2008/07/url-rewriting-with-urlrewriternet.html) does anyone have better suggestions?

Comment: Can you expand on the question. What is it that you don't like about the current solution? If you are merely looking for alternatives, maybe you should rephrase your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[System.Web.Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.aspx) is **part of .NET 3.5 SP1** and you can use it both for your ASP.NET WebForm-application and your MVC-application.

The **official ASP.NET site** has a good [**QuickStart Tutorial**](http://quickstarts.asp.net/3-5-extensions/mvc/ASPNETRouting.aspx) on System.Web.Routing.

Answer (score 3):

[ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) is also a good generic solution - works not only with ASP.NET but with any other system.

Comment: To clarify, any other ISAPI compatible (IIS) system.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach to consider is [URL **routing**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx). This is not the same as rewriting (rewriting involves changing one URL to another whilst routing involves directly mapping dynamic URLs to different parts of your application) and is not so easy to implement for an existing project, but if you're starting a project from scratch you might find this a better approach depending on your exact requirements. On the other hand, it may be no use to you at all, but at least you can make an informed decision!

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion made by Seb Nilsson I looked a bit all over google and found these nice examples:

- [aspnet routing goodbye url
  rewriting](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/aspnet-routing-goodbye-url-rewriting/)
- [using asp.net routing independent
  of mvc](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikeormond/archive/2008/05/14/using-asp-net-routing-independent-of-mvc.aspx)
- [using asp.net routing independent
  of mvc passing-parameters](http://bbits.co.uk/blog/archive/2008/05/19/using-asp.net-routing-independent-of-mvc---passing-parameters-to.aspx)

When working with IIS 6 it is important to have a look at this [Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/scothu/archive/2008/06/24/how-to-add-dynamic-data-to-an-existing-web-application.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

IIS 7 comes with a [rewrite module](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/05/31/urlrewrite-module-for-iis7.aspx)

You can find further links in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine#IIS) wikipedia article

Comment: Isn't this static in the Web.Config ?