# how to run php scripts without using php extension in an adress

Tags: php

As in title. I want to run `example.com/bar.php` by using `example.com/bar` as adress, but it doesn't wrong. How to set it?

Comment: Please take a look this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337695/remove-php-extension-with-php)

Answer (score 6):

The simplest approach: Call it */bar/index.php*

Other approaches include [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and [ForceType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_mime.html#forcetype) (assuming Apache).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using apache try adding this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^bar$ bar.php
```

Comment: It works very well, but how to change every file witch .php extension?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache look at [htaccess](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess.php) and mod_rewrite