# I am developing website using php and mysql.my each page file extension end with .php extension how do i avoid that?

Tags: php

I am developing website using php and mysql.my each page file extension end with .php extension how do i avoid that?what I have to do for that?

I don't have any framework language.I want to learn the mvc pattern. I want to know which framework is easy level because I always benefited by stack team.According to me stack team will give easy way for me.

For ex:http://academy.in/services.php I have change to http://www.academy.in/services

Comment: Look at Mod Rewrite in Apache https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: @AdRock better than my comment upvoted it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337695/remove-php-extension-with-php)

Comment: Actually this one may be a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821222/remove-php-extension-explicitly-written-for-friendly-url

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `.htaccess` file

A bit like this....

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?services/$ services.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: my thanks to each and every one I will follow all the link which you have listed here.my main question will there is no need of frame work here?because people are saying codeIgniter,kohana, I want to know which is easy? because i am strong in plain php and mysql