# Function Javascript return

Tags: javascript

Can you check if I return a function correct:

```
JS
$(eachsection).each(function() {
   listfunction();
}


function listfunction(){
  $(this).show();
  $(this).find('a.q_weblinksprite_med').attr("onclick", construct_url);
  $(this).find('.q_weblinksprite_med').text(itemTitle);
  $(this).find(".status").text(itemStatus);
  $(this).find('.q_rt_rowcell-1-title').text(itemCategory);
  $(this).find('.q_clipline').html(itemContent);
}
```

What I want is just to return all content from `listfunction()`. Thanks!

Comment: Right now you're not returning anything in any function..what is it exactly that you need?

Comment: from this snippet I see that you haven't closed each method, then try to write this way
`$(eachsection).each(listfunction);
function listfunction(){
  ...
  return $(this);
}`

Comment: well just print or debug what your method returns and you'll know if its correct... that's how i see it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337695/remove-php-extension-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted isn`t returning anything.

By the look, you could return a array

```
function listfunction(){
  var myReturn = {};
  $(this).show();
  myReturn['url'] = $(this).find('a.q_weblinksprite_med').attr("onclick", construct_url);
  myReturn['title'] = $(this).find('.q_weblinksprite_med').text(itemTitle);
  myReturn['status'] = $(this).find(".status").text(itemStatus);
  myReturn['category'] = $(this).find('.q_rt_rowcell-1-title').text(itemCategory);
  myReturn['content'] = $(this).find('.q_clipline').html(itemContent);
  return myReturn;
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: fix `var myReturn;`
furthermore you have to init this value as an object `var myReturn = {};`

Comment: Thanks @GudzDaniel, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `listfunction(`) from where you have it will cause you to lose scope. So if you are attempting to call `$(this).show()` and have it show the element you looped through, you would need to call it like this:

```
$(eachsection).each(function() {
   listfunction(this);
}


function listfunction(element){
  $(element).show();
  $(element).find('a.q_weblinksprite_med').attr("onclick", construct_url);
  $(element).find('.q_weblinksprite_med').text(itemTitle);
  $(element).find(".status").text(itemStatus);
  $(element).find('.q_rt_rowcell-1-title').text(itemCategory);
  $(element).find('.q_clipline').html(itemContent);
}
```