# How to make form shows only value in the URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to build an online Malayalam to English and English to Malayalam dictionary.

There are two online dictionaries available, however it is not perfect so I have plan to build a good dictionary.

When I check some of the website both of them are used get method at the same time URL details are totally different method. Let me show how it working:

[image]

[image]

At the same time my website showing like this:

[image]

Is there any option to my URL like other two websites? I think both websites are using PHP with jQuery.

Comment: You can use apache's mod_write to mangle a url however you want. I'd suggest first building your dictionary before worrying about the exact looks of the urls.

Comment: @Marc B I have a confusion about that , Do I need make any change in php code ?

Comment: If you mangle your urls, you'd have to make sure php knows what to look for. It's not transparent.

Comment: It should be transparent if you use GET variables in your php. If you manually parse the REQUEST_URI you'll have to code differently.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pretty URLs for search pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128796/pretty-urls-for-search-pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# make pretty urls work
RewriteRule ^dictionary/([^/]*)$ index.php?ml=$1 [L]

# redirect none-pretty urls
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ml=(.*)
RewriteRule ^$ /dictionary/%1 [L,R=302]
```

You'll also need some Javascript to catch the form's onsubmit, and change the url to not have the get parameters. You could do without, but that would result in an extra 302 request, and slow the pageload down a bit.

(PS make sure you php script return a 404 page if it can't find the word in the database.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the mod_rewrite from apache2,  it's a way for mask your parameters in a user friendly url.

You can read about thins in this tutorial:
http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

full docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/