# Search URL with no file extension

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, search-engine

I have made a search engine for my website and I want to know how to make the URL like Google Search or YouTube where it has...

```
http://sitename.com/search?q=search+query
```

I can only get it like this...

```
http://sitename.com/search.php?q=search+query
```

I want to find out how to take off the '.php'. putting it in a folder called search just mean it's like this...

```
http://sitename.com/search/?q=search+query
```

Hope you know what I mean and have enough information to help. Thanks.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: `RewriteRule ^search?q=(.*)$ /search.php?q=$1`
This doesn't work for me but that is how I want the URL. Any ideas why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory or in httpd.conf:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Once that is done apache will support:

```
http://sitename.com/search?q=search+query
```

by executing `search.php`

Answer (score 0):

inside sitename.com, create a directory called search. Your filename should not be search.php, use index.php instead. Then target it using the url, http://sitename.com/search/?q=search+query.

```
http://sitename.com/
search
index.php
```

That's obviously the simplest way. The other way is to use .htaccess mod_rewrite to rewrite your url. It might not be what you want, but would bring you close to what you want, if rename your file is not an issue

[Pretty URLs for search pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128796/pretty-urls-for-search-pages/128882#128882)